# When trying to get text value from UITextField, value is null/empty/garbage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a series of textfields the user will enter in values (one is a string the others numeric). When I try to get the text from:

```
NSString *strCal = txtfieldCal.text;
NSLog(@"cal entered: %a", strCal);
```

Returns:

```
calories Entered: -0x1.fd55804e2e26p+0
```

I have the outlets referenced correctly in IB.

I don't know if this matters or not, but I can populate the textfields on viewload, but I cannot get the value afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use %@ to put strings into NSLog. %a likely shows something else, - it looks like a number from the man page in terminal (type man printf)

NSLog(@"cal entered: %@", strCal);

Just thought that you may well WANT a number. Well you get a string -its a text field. To get a number, you call something like

NSLog(@"cal entered: %f", [strCal doubleValue]);

Comment: So what I am trying to say is that the code likely works... you are looking at the string as if it were a number.

Comment: thanks. I realized that shortly after i posted this comment and forgot to take this question down.